# Replace column values if it repeats the same character

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'team': ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green'],
               'points': [11, 7, 8, 10],
               'other': ["kk;aaa;;;", ";;bb;;", ";", ";;;;"]})
```

I would like to replace all cells that contain only `";"` with `""` (empty cells). There may be only 1 or many `";"` in a row. If there is anything in the cells other than `";"`, I would like to leave them as is.

In my dataframe the other column would become:

```
 other
kk;aaa;;;
;;bb;;
             #(nothing)
             #(nothing)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Series.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) with a regex pattern:

```
df['other'] = df.other.replace(r'^;{1,}$','', regex=True)

print(df)

     team  points      other
0     Red      11  kk;aaa;;;
1    Blue       7     ;;bb;;
2  Yellow       8           
3   Green      10
```

Explanation pattern `^;{1,}$`:

- `^` asserts position at start of the string
- `;` matches the character `;`
- `{1,}` matches the previous token (i.e. `;`) between one and unlimited times
- `$` asserts position at the end of the string

You can also use this on multiple columns, with [`df.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html). E.g.:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'team': ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green'],
               'points': [11, 7, 8, 10],
               'other': ["kk;aaa;;;", ";;bb;;", ";", ";;;;"],
               'other2': ["kk;aaa;;;", ";;bb;;", ";", ";;;;"]})

cols = ['other','other2']

df[cols] = df[cols].replace(r'^;{1,}$','', regex=True)

print(df)

     team  points      other     other2
0     Red      11  kk;aaa;;;  kk;aaa;;;
1    Blue       7     ;;bb;;     ;;bb;;
2  Yellow       8                      
3   Green      10
```

Comment: Also this works, if I wanted to apply it to multiple columns at the same time how would you advise me to do?

Answer (score 1):

here is one way to do it

```
# using apply, check if after replcing ; the string become of zero length
# if zero length, then return "" else the string
df['other'].apply(lambda x: "" if len(x.replace(";",''))==0 else x  )
```

```
0    kk;aaa;;;
1       ;;bb;;
2             
3             
Name: other, dtype: object
```

```
df['other2']=df['other'].apply(lambda x: "" if len(x.replace(";",''))==0 else x  )
df
```

```
    team    points  other       other2
0   Red     11      kk;aaa;;;   kk;aaa;;;
1   Blue    7       ;;bb;;      ;;bb;;
2   Yellow  8       ;   
3   Green   10      ;;;;
```

Comment: This works, if I wanted to apply it to multiple columns at the same time how would you advise me to do?

Comment: one way would be to run it separately for each of the columns, perhaps in a for loop that applies to each of the columns

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to call `applymap` on the dataframe and check if any string value consists entirely of `';'`s and mask those values using `mask()`. This works for the entire dataframe. You can of course use this method after selecting particular columns (instead of on the entire dataframe).

```py
df.mask(df.applymap(lambda x: isinstance(x, str) and set(x) == {';'}), '')
```

[image: res]